# Creating a clipping mask (or an after effects equivalent) within a shape layer to mask out a group of objects

Tags: layers, adobe-after-effects

Is there an easy way to create a clipping mask within an After Effects shape layer? It seems from my research that the merge path operator added to a shape layer can operate on single drawn vector objects but I am unsure if or how it can deal with groups of objects and if there is a method to clip them out.

The collection of screen shots hopefully illustrates what I am attempting to achieve.

[image]